# Magento2 : delete core cookies programmtically

Tags: magento-2.1.7, cookie

What is the similar code in Magneto2 to delete core cookies?

```
$cookies = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->get();
foreach($cookies as $cookieName) {
     Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->delete($cookieName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't this find this cookie. Might be magento2 remove this concept.

I have checked at the related files.

My suggestion to use php cookie variable `$_COOKIE`.

Check that `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager`.

Comment: Already found the delete cookie code `$this->cookieManager->deleteCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME);`, but in this code need to specify cookie name to delete, And my requirement is to delete complete cookies.

Comment: Yes, you  get   add / delete a cookie

Comment: But does not get any method which given list Cookie